# How to use clang-tidy with relative paths?

Tags: c++, clang, static-analysis

I'm using clang-tidy to perform some analysis on my C++ code. For this, I'm using the Clang JSON compilation database. It is working on the development machine but I cannot reuse the compilation database on another machine because all the paths in the compilation database are absolute and the other machine does not have the same current working directory. Here is an example in the JSON:

```
{
    "command": "clang++ -g -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -Iinclude -std=c++1y -Wextra -Wall -Qunused-arguments -Wuninitialized -Wsometimes-uninitialized -Wno-long-long -Winit-self -Wdocumentation -pedantic -Iinclude -ICatch/include -Werror -MD -MF debug/test/algorithm.cpp.d -o debug/test/algorithm.cpp.o -c test/algorithm.cpp",
    "directory": "/home/wichtounet/dev/cpp_utils_test",
    "file": "test/algorithm.cpp"
},
```

Ideally, the directory, should be the current working directory. I tried replace the absolute directory path with "." and let it empty and also remove it, but nothing worked.

Currently, the only solution I have is to use a script replace all the previous absolute paths by the paths of the current working directory, but this is highly unpractical...

Is it possible to use the same compilation database on different machine ?